# pass line to function - overwrite using sed line by line - BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

why this code not work? What's the problem of passing $line to a function?

```
function a {
    echo $1 | grep $2
}
while read -r line; do
    a $line "LAN"
done < database.txt
```

Another question, i have to overwrite line by line a txt file possibly using sed command.But not all the line, only the part to change. Something like this:

```
while read -r line; do
    echo $line | sed "s/STRING1/STRING2/"
done < namefile
```

EDIT

I give you an example for my second question.

input file:

```
LAN 1:
[text]11111[text]
[text]22222[text]
[text]33333[text]
LAN 2:
[text]11111[text]
[text]22222[text]
[text]33333[text]
output file:

LAN 1:
[text]44444[text]
[text]22222[text]
[text]33333[text]
LAN 2:
[text]11111[text]
[text]22222[text]
[text]33333[text]
```

I have to overwrite database.txt so i think to do this line by line using a counter for LAN. This is my code:

```
while read -r line; do
echo "$line" | grep -q LAN
    if [ $? = "0" ]; then
        net_count=$((net_count+1))
    fi
    if [ $net_count = <lan choose before> ]; then   # variable that contains lan number chosen by user                  
        echo "$line" | fgrep -q "11111"         
        if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then                             
            echo $line | sed "s/11111/44444/" > database.txt
            break
        fi
    fi
done < database.txt
```

Thank you all

Comment: This is, bluntly, a horrible idea. Starting any external command has a very nontrivial performance cost -- if you're going to do line-by-line logic, that should be done in native bash, or in a **single** invocation of an external tool.

Comment: ...beyond that, you've got the quotes exactly backwards. `a "$line" LAN` would be correct -- expansions need to be quoted; literals with no whitespace, glob characters, or expandable elements don't.

Comment: Likewise, `echo "$line"`, not `echo $line`. These are issues that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch automatically.

Comment: ...see also [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put $line in quotes for the whole line to be considered as a single parameter. Else, every space character splits the strings as multiple parameter to the function:

```
#!/bin/bash
function a {
     echo "$1" | grep "$2"
}
while read -r line; do
    a "$line" "LAN"
done < database.txt
```

And for the second question, if you want to print only the lines that you modify, you can use the following code:

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line" | sed -n "s/STRING1/STRING2/p"
done < namefile
```

Here, `-n` will omit the lines that do not match the string; and the flag `p` makes sure to print the lines that match.

Comment: You're leaving quoting bugs in. Needs to be `echo "$1" | grep "$2"`, and `echo "$line"`.

Comment: ...otherwise, if your line contains `*`, then `echo $1` will be writing a list of filenames; and `grep "$2"` can be passed a completely arbitrary number of separate arguments.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, thanks for that.. editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Running `sed` once for every line is typically over a thousand times slower than running just one `sed` instance processing your whole file of input. Don't do it.

If you want to do string manipulation on a line-by-line basis, use native bash primitives for the purpose, as documented in [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100):

```
a() {
  local line=$1 regex=$2
  if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  fi
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
  a "$line" LAN
done <database.txt
```

Likewise, for substring replacements, an appropriate [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) primitive exists:

```
while read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "${line//STRING1/STRING2}"
done < namefile
```

That said, those approaches are only appropriate if you need to iterate line-by-line. Typically, it makes more sense to use a single `grep` or `sed` operation, and iterate over the *results* of those calls if you need to do native bash operations. For instance, the following iterates over the output from `grep`, as emitted by a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
regex=LAN
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "Read line from grep: $line"
done < <(grep -e "$regex" <database.txt)
```